# Parsing XML Elements using TinyXML

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, tinyxml

**UPDATE: Still not working :( I have updated the code portion to reflect what I currently have.**

This should be a pretty easy question for people who have used TinyXML. I'm attempting to use TinyXML to parse through an XML document and pull out some values. I figured out how to add in the library yesterday, and I have successfully loaded the document (hey, it's a start).

I've been reading through the manual and I can't quite figure out how to pull out individual attributes. After Googling around, I haven't found an example of my specific example, so perhaps someone here who has used TinyXML can help out. Below is a slice of the XML, and where I have started to parse it.

**XML:**

```
<EGCs xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <card type="EGC1">
    <offsets>
      [ ... ]
    </offsets>
  </card>

   <card type="EGC2">
    <offsets>
      [ ... ]
    </offsets>
  </card>
</EGCs>
```

**Loading/parsing code:**

```
TiXmlDocument doc("EGC_Cards.xml");
if(doc.LoadFile())
{
    TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
    TiXmlElement* pElem;
    TiXmlHandle hRoot(0);
    pElem = hDoc.FirstChildElement().Element();
    if (!pElem) return false;
    hRoot = TiXmlHandle(pElem);

    //const char *attribval = hRoot.FirstChild("card").ToElement()->Attribute("card");
    pElem = hDoc.FirstChild("EGCs").Child("card", 1).ToElement();
    if(pElem)
    {
        const char* tmp = pElem->GetText();
        CComboBox *combo = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EGC_CARD_TYPE);
        combo->AddString(tmp);
    }
}
```

***I want to pull out each card "type" and save it to a string to put into a combobox. How do I access this attribute member?***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**After a lot of playing around with the code, here is the solution! (With help from [HERE](http://bytes.com/topic/xml/answers/745647-reading-xml-file-using-tinyxml))**

```
TiXmlDocument doc("EGC_Cards.xml");
combo = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EGC_CARD_TYPE);

if(doc.LoadFile())
{
    TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
    TiXmlElement *pRoot, *pParm;
    pRoot = doc.FirstChildElement("EGCs");
    if(pRoot)
    {
        pParm = pRoot->FirstChildElement("card");
        int i = 0; // for sorting the entries
        while(pParm)
        {
            combo->InsertString(i, pParm->Attribute("type"));
            pParm = pParm->NextSiblingElement("card");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
else 
{
    AfxMessageBox("Could not load XML File.");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there should be a Attribute method that takes and attribut name as parameter see: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlElement.html

from the documentation I see the code would look like:

```
    hRoot.FirstChildElement("card").ToElement()->Attibute("type");
```

However for the type of thing you are doing I would use XPATH if at all possible. I have never used it but the TinyXPath project may be helpful if you choose to go that route the link is: http://tinyxpath.sourceforge.net/

Hope this helps.

The documentation I am using to help you from is found at: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/hierarchy.html

Comment: Attribute is not a member of TiXmlHandle :\

Comment: @Jon Let me know if that gets you closer.

Comment: I found my own solution. See my answer above.

Comment: Gald that you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to get the attribute `type` from the element `card`. So in your code it should be something like:

```
const char * attribval = hRoot.FirstChild("card").ToElement()->Attribute("card");
```

Comment: I tried that, where &someCharArray is CString tmp;

I get the following error:

'const char *TiXmlElement::Attribute(const char *,int *) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'int *'

Comment: Sorry, that was for getting an integer value. Have a look at the function `QueryStringAttribute` which is in the TinyXML reference, that should be what you are looking for!

Comment: I'll have a look and report back. Thanks Iceaway.